# How can I inject store in pipe?

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

In current situation, I want to transform the data using pipe.
But inside that pipe, I want to access store to get some preference.
Is it possible to inject store inside pipe?

Comment: Yes you can inject

Answer (score 0):

```
function yourProcessOrServiceMethod(input: YourType): string { ... }

@Pipe({ name: 'yourPipe' })
export class YourPipeDefinition implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: YourType): string // it can be other than string
    return yourProcessOrServiceMethod(value);
  }
}
```

```js
@NgModule({..., providers: [..., YourPipeDefinition] })
export class AnyModule { ... } // but recommend define in AppModule
```

```
{{ compData | yourPipe }}
```

Another example: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-custom-pipes-angular